# What is the function of glActiveTexture and GL_TEXTURE0 in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm finding a way to understand why `glActiveTexture` is needed. I have the code below:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

If I imagine that the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is a picture's frame hanging on the wall and `textureId` is the real picture, the `glBindTexture` is the only command for assigning a real picture to the frame, so, what are `GL_TEXTURE0` and `glActiveTexture`?

Will my code below work fine?

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, .....)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...)
```

I'm currently working with OpenGL2.1.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> If I imagine that the GL_TEXTURE_2D is a picture's frame hangging on the wall and textureId is the real picture,

Actually a very good analogy :)

> so, what GL_TEXTURE0 and glActiveTexture are?

Think about a wall with multiple picture frames, the first frame being labeled GL_TEXTURE0, the second GL_TEXTURE1 and so on.

Comment: so, when setting up the texture (`glTexParrameteri`, `glTexImage2D`, ...) are we need to call `glActiveTexture`?

Comment: Yes, because there is no parameter in glTexImage2D to say if you're talking about GL_TEXTURE0 or GL_TEXTURE1.

Comment: @datenwolf: One more question :D: If I use more than one texture in fragment shader (IE `uniform sampler2D tex1; uniform sampler2D tex2; ...` then how I call `glActiveTexture`?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: You use glActiveTexture units to put "images" into their "unit" frame `GL_TEXTURE0 + n`, and in the shader you set the sampler to just the value `n`. Yes, this is an inconsistency, but who cares? Just put a `GL_TEXTURE0+` into all calls of `glActiveTexture`, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 23):

OpenGL introduced multitexturing at some point (which is basically *using more than one texture on one geometry pass*); in order to keep older code working, they couldn't just add additional parameter to all the functions. That's why you have to explicitly specify which texture unit you are addressing.

Comment: So, Are we need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` or `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)`, ... before using them in new OpenGL version (2.1+)?

Comment: Well, yes, because each texture unit can be of any type from previous versions.

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: Only if you're using the fixed function pipeline. If you're using shaders the use of texture sampling is determined by the shader program.